# EclipseLink does not find my Converter class

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, converters

I have a JPA @Entity 'RecipestepBO' which uses a @Converter:

```
@Entity
@Converter( name="UnitConverter", converterClass=com.lemcke.share.recipe.Unit.class )
@Table(name = "recipestep")
public class RecipestepBO {
...
private Unit rpsunit = null;
...
@Column( name="rpsunit" )
@Convert( "UnitConverter" )
public Unit getRpsunit() { return rpsunit; }
...
}
```

And the converter class (which is in fact an enumeration) in the same package:

```
package com.lemcke.share.recipe;

public enum Unit implements Converter {
Liter ( "l" )
....
all overloaded methods from the Converter
....
}
```

Starting the application results in the following EclipseLink exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [testPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7198] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Class: [com.lemcke.share.recipe.Unit] was not found while converting from class names to classes.

The entity is written in the persistence.xml file. The converter 'Unit' is not (because its not an entity).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Converter should be a class, not an enum, not sure an enum would work, or make sense.

Try a class, and if still not luck, include the full exception stack trace (including caused by).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. A converter CANNOT be an enum (for whatever reason).